# Is there a way to identify error cause for a HTML link element?

Tags: html

The [HTML link element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) supports `onerror` handler to react to an error loading the linked resource. However, the `onerror` handler accepts an `Event` object that does not seem to be carrying any information about an actual error cause. For example, loading of the referenced resource could fail due to some internal server error (i.e. HTTP 500) or some security restrictions (i.e. HTTP 403).

Is there a way to identify the root cause for a `link` element failing to load its resource?

Comment: no, the [error event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error) doesn't provide any information on the actual error which fired it. That is true for every resource. The [onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) attribute is just an handler. The only way is to look into your dev-tools, in the network panel.

Comment: I feel dirty even suggesting this, but you could [replay it as an AJAX request to fetch "a" status code](http://jsfiddle.net/jevrackq/). Of course this won't necessarily help diagnosing intermittent file load issues.

Comment: @Kaiido - That's not handled by `onerror` to begin with, so the browser doesn't interpret that as an "error". From what I ascertain, since the OP references it, server-related responses is what is wanted here.

Comment: yes.. the AJAX request was my first thought too, but it does "feel dirty". However, it just might be a necessary evil in this case. Thank you.

Comment: It just depends on how desperate you are to get an error status code. Also note it won't work cross-site unless you're using CORS (which I'm guessing here, not tested).

Comment: @Kaiido - Yeah, Chrome doesn't treat that as an error. Go figure. I still don't think that's exactly what the OP is after, but caveat emptor.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Could you please post your suggestion to use an AJAX request as an answer, so that it could be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feels like a dirty hack, but you can replay it as an AJAX request to fetch a status code (assuming the error isn't intermittent):

```
var link = document.createElement('link');

link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = 'mystylesheet.css';
link.onerror = function (event) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            console.log('error on ' + link.href + ' request:', xmlhttp.status);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", link.href, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};

document.body.appendChild(link);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jevrackq/

As Kaiido [specified](http://jsfiddle.net/jevrackq/) (demonstrates error in Firefox, but not Chrome), this will only handle server-related HTTP errors, not errors on the browser-side (such as, the wrong mimetype for the element, e.g., `rel='stylesheet'` but an `image/jpeg` is given in the markup).